# IO completion port (object relation)

Tags: multithreading, threadpool, iocp

I begin learning about IOCP, I see some object: Io completion port, thread pool,  thread, completion packet. Please show me relation of them. Many thanks.

Comment: Ever tried reading the documentation?

Comment: thank @SergeyA, i'm not clear it.